# Slick schema/design guidelines

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Suppose I have such schema (simplified), using slick 2.1:

```
// Banks
case class Bank(id: Int, name: String)

class Banks(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bank](tag, "banks") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name) <> (Bank.tupled, Bank.unapply)
}

lazy val banks = TableQuery[Banks]
```

Each bank has, say, 1:1 `BankInfo`, which I keep in separate table:

```
// Bank Info
case class BankInfo(bank_id: Int, ...)

class BankInfos(tag: Tag) extends Table[BankInfo](tag, "bank_infos") {
  def bankId = column[Int]("bank_id", O.PrimaryKey)
  ...
}

lazy val bankInfos = TableQuery[BankInfos]
```

And each bank has associated 1:M `BankItems`:

```
// Bank Item
case class BankItem(id: Int, bank_id: Int, ...)

class BankItems(tag: Tag) extends Table[BankItem](tag, "bank_items") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def bankId = column[Int]("bank_id")
  ...
}

lazy val bankItems = TableQuery[BankItems]
```

So, if I used ORM, I would have had convenient accessors for associated data, something like `bank.info` or `bank.items`. I've read "Migrating from ORMs", and I understand that Slick doesn't support full relation mapping, though I've seen example where `foreignKey` was used.

Basically, where should I place my code to access related data (I want to access all `BankItems` for some `Bank`, and its `BankInfo`). Should it be implemented in `case class`es, or in `Table` classes, or elsewhere? Can someone give me a practical advice on what is a "standard practice" in this case?

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/satendrakumar06/slick-for-production
This has been written in slick 3.0.1. I would recommend use Slick 3.0.1 instead of 2.1.0 if you going to start.

Comment: @Sky Thanks, though it looks overcomplicated for such a basic task.

Comment: @dimtry  Yes, you are right. Because all database access methods are independent from database so you can change database according to environment or you need.For eg: H2 for unit testing and MySql for production.
If you like unit testing then It may be helpful .